# The ambiguous star operator on function name

Tags: c++, c, pointers, function-pointers

Just a minimum working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(char* str)
{
    printf("%s\n", str);
}

main()
{
   foo("foo");
   (* foo)("* foo");
}
```

which outputs

```
foo
* foo
```

I thought the function name should be the address of the routine in the code segment, so the star operator should return an executable instruction. But how does this operator work here actually?
Thanks for shedding some light.

Comment: May as well toss `(&foo)("& foo")` in there while you're at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, functions are not values, you cannot "dereference a pointer to a function" and get something (a value) that makes sense.

Therefore, trying to dereference and call such a pointer has no additional effect, it's the same as calling through the pointer in the first place.

Comment: @Angew Thanks, I clarified that I was mainly talking about C.

Comment: C++, on the other hand, *does* differentiate between a pointer to function and a reference to function. You get the latter by dereferencing the former. It's just that operator `()` is defined for pointers to functions, and an implicit conversion from (reference to) function to pointer to function exists.

Comment: Reworded the comment accordingly :-)